# How to put ansi-term state in mode line?

Tags: ansi-term

Is there a way to put the ansi-term state (`char-mode` or `term-mode`) in the mode line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean term-char-mode and term-line-mode? These are printed by default in the mode-line here (Emacs 28.1 and 29.0.50). Here is how it looks when starting from `emacs -q`:

[image]

[image]

So then we can look up the `mode-line-format` where we find that the modes are formatted via the `mode-line-modes` variable. Finally from that variable we find that the ':char/:line' part is formatted via the `mode-line-process` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'mode-line-process to your mode-line format.